# magento customize html print order

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to customize the html print order (url http://www.yoursite.com/index.php/sales/order/print/order_id/8/ ) but I can't find the right file to do this.

I'm working on template/sales/order/print files but all the changes I made aren't visible.

could you please give me a hint?

Thanks a lot

Best regards

EDIT: ok, I've found the file that I need to modify, it is print-phtml in app/design/frontend/default/MYTEMPLATE/template/sales/order

Now I'd like to add product description in each row in this html print page, but I don't know how I can do this

There is

```
<?php $_items = $_order->getItemsCollection(); ?>
<?php $_count = $_items->count(); ?>
<?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
<?php if ($_item->getParentItem()) continue; ?>
<tbody>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
</tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

so I think that I have to modify something in $this->getItemHtml($_item) but I have no idea where is this getItemHtml

could you please help me? thanks a lot

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to change template files in the default or base package, while your site has a custom one? Or a wrong theme?

Comment: Or any other module has overwritten path to this file.

Comment: my template (respond theme) hasn't got this folder, so I've copied it from base to my template, then I've modified invoice.phtml but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file you have to edit is the \sales\order\items\renderer\default.phtml , but changes you make here will also appear on the order view page.
To avoid this, you can use the following condition in this phtml (there is also an example in the original version):

```
<?php if ($this->getPrintStatus()): ?>
....        
<?php endif;?>
```

.. and for similar issues in the future: on the admin panel, in System/Configuration menu if you switch to "Store view", you will find an option under Advanced/Developer tab called "Template path hints". If you set it to "yes", you will see the template pathes in the frontend, embedded inline next to each block. [How to use template path hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/)